# Spectral structure of sinusoidal model

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

Let us consider the following code:

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x);
end
```

I know peaks in the Fourier domain are represented at these frequencies, which are present in the signal.

For example, let us take the plot of the Fourier transform of this signal:

```
y=generate1(3,500,1);
```

and  plot

```
plot(abs(fft(y)))
```

[image]

but clearly it does not show peaks at the frequencies given in the signal.  What is the problem?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: i can't understand what is problem there,because in my mind it should work without problem

Comment: But it looks exactly like it should. You are sampling a signal with frequencies 100Hz and 200Hz with a sampling frequency of 16.66kHz (represented by 500 in your diagram). So your signal has a rather low frequency relative to the sampling frequency. So your components should be at 6 and 12, which seems to be the case in the plot.

Comment: but peaks must be at frequency   100 and 200  is not it?

Comment: yes i wannted to avoid aliasing,but maybe i made some mistake?

Comment: You would have to shift and rescale the diagram, that is, cut the part from 250 to 500 and paste it in the negative range, shifting by -500 (or cut it at all), and multiply the x scale by 50/3/500 kHz, that is, 33.3Hz so that then the point 3 goes to 100Hz and the point 6 to 200Hz.

Comment: No mistake, but your safeguards are too safe.

Comment: please could you tell me how to  do it in matlab?

Comment: or please post this as  solution, i will upvote and will accept,at the same time my reputation will be increased

Comment: Just take this plot and only show the [0:20] range.

Comment: like xlim([0 20])?

Comment: @LutzL  i did not understand this part Just take this plot and only show the [0:20] range,how could i do it in matlab?

Comment: A=abs(fft(y)); plot(A([0:20])) or similar, I'm not sure about matlab range syntax.

Comment: You can find another explanation here: 
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/plotting-magnitude-and-phase-for-frequency-spectrum/13559#13559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets analyze the computation. Your function takes $N$ periods of the $100Hz$ sine wave and correspondingly $2N$ periods of the $200Hz$ sine wave and samples them in $m$ equidistant points.

Then you perform an FFT of size $m$. If we forget for the moment that there is a factor of 100Hz used in the production, we have sampled waves of $N$ and $2N$ full oscillations, and the FFT detects or handles sinusoids with up to $m/2$ full oscillations.

In the plot from of the FFT result scaled from 0 to m one would expect the first wave at position N, the second at position 2N, and the mirror frequencies at m-1-N and m-1-2N.

In your example with N=3 and m=500, the 100Hz component is at position 3 and the 200Hz component at position 6.

To get more striking results, either reduce the range in the display to $[0:10N]$ or similar, or choose the magnitudes of m and N closer together, m=8N to m=20N should work well.

---

Added matlab interna: the fft command produces the DC at position 1, the first array position. The FFT with sampling frequency $f_s$ and $m$ samples produces a sampling of the frequency spectrum ranging from $-f_s/2$ to $f_s/2$ in $m$ steps, assuming $m$ is even.

The fft command arranges these frequencies by wrapping around at $fs/2$, so that a component for $f>fs/2$ in reality is a component for $f-f_s<0$. For real signals, the negative spectrum is essentially the same as the positive, complex conjugation is the only difference. So one can just disregard the second half of the result of fft for visualization purposes.

The `generate1` function should at least also return the sampling frequency `fs=(f1*m)/N`. Then

```
m=500;
y,fs=generate1(3,m,1);
A=abs(fft(y))/m;
f=(0:1:m-1)*fs;
plot(f(1:m/2),A(1:m/2))
```

produces the full spectrum with correct scale. Replace `m/2` in the plot command with a smaller number to display only parts of the spectrum.

Comment: in ploting how should i use  [0:10N]?

Comment: matlab has not  indexed 0 or negative

Comment: i want to show  peaks exactly at 200 and 100

Comment: Since position 1 is frequency 0, shift everything by 1. From what I wrote, you can set N=100, m=1000, or introduce a proper frequency scale f=(0:1:m-1)*100.0/N to then plot(f(1:10*N), A(1:10*N)).

Comment: will not it be  too much sampling frequency?

Comment: yes now i got answers,by the ways peaks are also at  800 and 900,are they normal right?

Comment: Yes, since a sine wave of frequency $f$ has frequency components at $f$ and also at $-f$. The FFT is periodic, that is, the second half in reality is the negative part of the spectrum. So 800Hz in reality is -200Hz, and 900Hz is -100Hz. There is some FFT-shift command to automatically normalize this.

Comment: thanks for helping,so finally  which on is  better to  change sampling frequency or  change scales?i mean  everytime i choose different sampling frequency,how should i determine relevant scales?

Comment: and by the way merry christmas and happy new year

Comment: how to calculate  fs?