# Get spectral picture from a wavelet transform

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet, power-spectral-density

According to [my previous question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13527/spectral-structure-of-sinusoidal-model), I have changed the generate command to:

```
y=generate1(100,1000,1);
```

and got the following picture:

[image]

Now I want to test a wavelet transform on the same signal, which of course exists in Matlab, but I have  one thing which I should  clarify: generally, as I know large scale values correspond to small frequencies and small scale values to large frequencies.  So, how should I determine if the given frequencies are small or large? Also, which wavelet transform should i use?

For example:

```
m=cwt(y,1:100,'sym2');
```

and plot it

```
plot(m)
```

[image]

How should I read the second picture? What kind of information can I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
m=cwt(y,1:100,'sym2','plot');
colormap(pink)
```

Result (btw, I cannot reproduce your curve in time domain with the function `generate1`):

[image]

Low scale values compress the wavelet and correlate better with high frequencies. While high scale values stretch the wavelet and correlate better with the low frequency content of the signal.

Comment: does this picture shows  peaks at  given frequency's in signal?

Comment: They are CWT coefficients (http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/continuous-wavelet-transform.html#bsor2go), but I guess it is somehow equivalent to the power within the scaling window.