# Plotting magnitude and phase for frequency spectrum

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

I would like to find the frequency spectrum by drawing magnitude and phase for the following signal:

```
S=sin(2*pi*100*t)+cos(pi*500*t);

X=sinc(2*pi*t);
```

Is there something particular to this problem that I should be noticing?

We can easily find the spectra giving a time domain like

```
t=0:0.01:0.1;
```

And using the `fft` command for both signals

```
X=fft(S);
```

What did they mean by drawing the magnitude and phase?

Comment: @lennon310 Please try to grab any spelling or grammar issues in the text as well.

Comment: @jonsca Thank you Jonsca. Will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 2):

for plotting magnitude spectrum versus frequency you can use the following script:

```
t = 0:0.001:0.2;
s = sin(2*pi*100*t)+cos(pi*500*t);
S = abs(fftshift(fft(s)));

Fs = 1000;
df = 1000/(length(s));
f = -Fs/2:df:Fs/2-df;

plot(f,S);
```

Here I used your first signal and plotted its magnitude spectrum. You must notice for your signal `min choosable Nyquist frequency` is 500 Hz But we use it two times of it(which is 1000Hz), because we also want to see the part before f =0 in the frequency spectrum. Using this we find `df(delta f)` frequency spacing. frequency vector must be multiples of df. By this way spectrum will be drawn correctly.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For plotting the magnitude and phase using the above, but with the following (slight) modifications

```
S=fftshift(fft(s))  
figure  
plot(f,abs(S)); %Plot of magnitude  
figure   
plot(f,unwrap(angle(S))); %Plot of phase
```

Note - unwrap() tries to take care of any 2*pi jumps in the phase.